# Postgresql : "OR" does'nt work like I want

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got some problem with my request :

This request work :

```
SELECT o.nom, a.url, a.apikey 
FROM Organisation o, API a, Acheter ac
WHERE o.id_organisation = a.id_organisation 
AND ac.id_organisation = o.id_organisation 
AND ac.id_device = :idd ;
```

This request work :

```
SELECT o.nom, a.url, a.apikey
FROM Organisation o, API a, Louer l
WHERE o.id_organisation = a.id_organisation 
AND l.id_organisation = o.id_organisation 
AND l.id_device = :idd 
AND l.dateLocation + l.dureeLocation * interval '1 day' < CURRENT_DATE;
```

But when I put an "OR" between the both requests, it doesn't work :

```
SELECT o.nom, a.url, a.apikey
FROM Organisation o, API a, Acheter ac, Louer l

WHERE o.id_organisation = a.id_organisation 

AND (ac.id_organisation = o.id_organisation 
AND ac.id_device = :idd)

OR (l.id_organisation = o.id_organisation 
AND l.id_device = :idd 
AND l.dateLocation + l.dureeLocation * interval '1 day' < CURRENT_DATE);
```

I've tried to put parentheses, but the request still doesn't work.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becomes easier to read when you use joins:

```
SELECT o.nom, a.url, a.apikey
FROM Organisation AS o
LEFT JOIN API AS a ON o.id_organisation = a.id_organisation
LEFT JOIN Acheter AS ac ON ac.id_organisation = o.id_organisation
WHERE ac.id_device = :idd ;

SELECT o.nom, a.url, a.apikey
FROM Organisation o
LEFT JOIN API AS a ON o.id_organisation = a.id_organisation
LEFT JOIN Louer AS l ON l.id_organisation = o.id_organisation
WHERE l.id_device = :idd
AND l.dateLocation + l.dureeLocation * interval '1 day' < CURRENT_DATE;
```

And now combine them:

```
SELECT o.nom, a.url, a.apikey
FROM Organisation o
LEFT JOIN API AS a ON o.id_organisation = a.id_organisation
LEFT JOIN Louer AS l ON l.id_organisation = o.id_organisation
LEFT JOIN Acheter AS ac ON ac.id_organisation = o.id_organisation

WHERE ac.id_device = :idd
      OR (
        l.id_device = :idd AND
        l.dateLocation + l.dureeLocation * interval '1 day' < CURRENT_DATE
      )
```

Now where is the difference? You had a mistake in your parentheses. The `o.id_organisation = a.id_organisation` was canceled out by the or-condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend:

```
SELECT o.nom, a.url, a.apikey 
FROM Organisation o JOIN
     API a
     ON o.id_organisation = a.id_organisation 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Acheter ac
              WHERE ac.id_organisation = o.id_organisation AND
                    ac.id_device = :idd
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM louer l
              WHERE l.id_device = :idd AND
                    l.dateLocation + l.dureeLocation * interval '1 day' < CURRENT_DATE
            );
```

Note the use of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.